# Authenticate application in GKE Pod

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I want to allow some of my GKE Pods to access the Cloud Trace API. I have a Java application, that works as expected when a manually generated access token has been provided to it, or if it's run on my local machine with the `application default credentials` configured. I also have configured the Workflow Identity Pool with GKE Metadata Server for a service account, and with GCloud CLI, I can generate an access token in the Pod manually.

I need to connect the 2 parts, and make the application generate the OAuth token automatically (and refresh it as needed), just like it does on my local machine. During startup, the application only finds the GKE Node's service account credentials, that don't have the required permissions.

I use libraries from google to authenticate and handle invocations to the Trace API. For all I know, the GKE Metadata Server is working, since I can generate an access token within the pod with `gcloud auth print-access-token`.

UPDATE:

When above I said "from the pod", it was actually a test-pod, not the actual application. I forgot to set the correct service account in the application's pod. Now everything seems to be in order.

Comment: Glad you solved it.  If you are not already, I'd also recommend using GKE Workload Identity for better security of credentials:  https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity

Comment: @GariSingh as I said, I already had workload identity configured when I asked this question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the details of your setup or what control you have over your cloud infrastructure.

From an architectural viewpoint, GCP Workload Identity Management is a good solution to your problem.
It lets you configure your pod's kubernetes service account to map to a google cloud service account outside of the cluster, the procedure is well documented.

See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity